# spring boot logback does display variables from Mdc filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, log4j, spring-logback

I have spring boot restFull application that running on linux server as spring boot (not installed on tomcat server).

I'm using logback logger.

I try to display the existing user code from the request on each line I print via logback logger.

to do that i use MDC filter [ MDC.put("userName",req.getUserPrincipal())  ].
when i run it in my eclipse it's work well as exprected.

**but when i packed the project and install it on server (spring boot application) the user name is empty(blank)**

```
public class MdcFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            
            String user = getUserPrincipal(request);
            System.out.println("MdcFilter save user="+user);
            MDC.put("userName", user);

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("userName");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    private String getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal == null)
            return null;
        String name = principal.getName();
        String[] parts = name.split("@");
        int iWord = Math.min(0, parts.length - 2);
        String userId = parts[iWord];
        return userId;
    }
    
}
```

> this is the bean that register the mdc filter

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean mdcFilterRegisterationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        MdcFilter mdcFilter = new MdcFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(mdcFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(10);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

in logback.xml

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%-8X{userName}|%-5level{5}|%-100msg | %class{40}.%method{20}:%line |%n
    </pattern>
</encoder>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.work.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webapp</name>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.???????.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spnego-filter</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kohsuke.stapler</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>webapp</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources/static</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>/webapp</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem

Comment: I have the same issue because the filter thread is different than the service one.